# AngularJs service binding not updating

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I am trying to find a way to create a service that can sit at my highest level scope and hold variables such as the user state and whatever else.

Right now I am trying to create a simple example in which I bind the numbers together. However the UI layer never updates unless I force my angular to go get the value again.

What happens if you remove the line that says getNumber() you see that the number on the html never updates. I tried calling $apply and that give me an error that one is already in effect.

Code:

```
$scope.update = function () {
        SampleService.update();

//Forcing the number to be updated by asking the service to return it
        $scope.number = SampleService.getNumber();

    };
//Why doesn't this force $scope.number to change as SampleServce.number changes?
    $scope.number = SampleService.number;
```

Service:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('Services')
    .service('SampleService', SampleService);

SampleService.$inject = ['$http'];

function SampleService($http) {

    var Service = {
        number: 0
    };


    Service.update = function ()
    {
        Service.number += 1;
    };

    Service.getNumber = function ()
    {
        return Service.number;
    };

    return Service;
}
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because `number` is a primitive property of `Service`.  Setting `$scope.number` (which is a primitive) to be equal to `SampleService.number` (which is also a primitive) is done ByVal, not ByRef.

Adding the `SampleService` *object itself* to `$scope` would create a reference, as would returning any *objects* that are properties of `SampleService`.  Here is one example of referencing the service rather than just the single primitive property:

```
$scope.service = SampleService;

{{service.number}}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/eWk8lZRa0dGIhd2I8h9t?p=preview

Comment: I just figured that out but instead of storing $scope.service = SampleService I do this, $scope.State = SampleService.getData() which returns the Service object from SampleService. Is there any benefit or downsides to our two similar but different methods?

Comment: the only difference between setting it directly and using a `getData()` is that by using a `getData()` function, your service doesn't have to return anything.

Comment: Thank you for answering this question and the one in the comments. I like my getData approach because of a personal reason I can literally see that I am expecting my data.

Comment: I would like to thank you one more time because of getting this issue fixed I could implement a lot of code today. If you would like to see what I accomplished check out the new features at app.baileysproject.com

Answer (score 1):

Numbers, string and other basic types are passed as values, and not references, and hence you get the actual number (i.e. 7) and not the address of Service.number.

Only way I know to circumvent this is to return a object, and use a property on this instead.

Comment: I thought that was what I am doing at the bottom of my serivce, where I return the variable Service. Because in the controllers I can call methods on my SampleService that are exposed inside of Service at the SampleService level.